# PHP matrix splitting algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, matrix

I have the following issue:

Given a sqare matrix (n×n) I want to be able to split it in a certain number of distinct areas. I made the splitting by diagonals but I'm not happy with the result. I want to be able to split the matrix based on at least 2 functions(chosen randomly). The problem with that is that I don't have any ideea on how to implement such splitting. Any suggestion is welcome. Please note that the small parts will have to be recombined later on in the application.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed some examples of what you're trying to achieve, together with the code you've written so far; because otherwise you've not really made it clear what you're trying to do

Comment: I don't have any code in place yet, I have a matrix and I want to use it as a sort of map. A map can be split into areas, for example costal areas, urban areas, wasteland areas and some other types. On these areas i want certain types of tiles, for example you can't have a mountain in a costal area. And I need a conceptual idea on how to split the map. My first guess is that I have to split it in little m×m parts where m is a fraction of n. Any other solutions are apreciated.